# how to upgrade typo3 7.6.0 to typo3 7.6.1?

Tags: typo3, upgrade, typo3-7.x

there is an upgrade to version 7.6.1.
We fixed a lot of bugs Version 7.6.0
in install toll, Upgrade Wizard :

> No updates to perform!

Comment: This question isn't clear at all, please specify what you've tried and what exactly is your error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That update is a patch level update, they usually don't require any upgrade wizards (there are exceptions, check the release notes).

To do the update, just replace the old TYPO3 core with the new one (easy thing when using symlinks), and then clear all caches from the install tool. If you are using symlinks to include the core, the install tool can do this for you. There is a button for it.

If you have modified the TYPO3 core, those changes will be lost. Better provide the fixes to the TYPO3 community, the [various contribution walkthrough tuturials](https://wiki.typo3.org/Contribution_Walkthrough_Tutorials) give you details.